# Segmentation fault in C, can't seem to find the cause

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't seem to find the cause of the segmentation fault in the code below. The code crashes in the line with the comment, after jumping back to main() from evaluate(). I looked at this code with gdb, and it seems everything is ok within the evaluate function - Output is filled in correctly, however after I return to main, nothing in the memory can be accessed. "p j" in gdb return an memory not accessible error, as does trying to print any other variable. I checked if the stack maybe had to many values, but increasing the stack size does not help.

The crazy thing is that I can solve this error, but I have no idea why it changes anything. If I add, anywhere in evaluate(), an int declaration (eg. `int iAmNotUsedEver;`) then the code suddenly doesn't cause a segmentation error and works perfectly in gdb. 
Edit: Dynamically allocating node[116] in evaluate (`int *node = malloc(116*sizeof(int));`) also resolves the issue, but again I have no idea why?

Evaluate function: (I removed part of the code, otherwise it would be way too long)

```
void evaluate(int *parameter, int output[][16]) {
    int node[116];
    node[0] = 0;
    output[0][0] = !node[0];
    node[1] = parameter[0];
    output[0][1] = !node[1];
    output[0][2] = !node[0];
    ...
    node[34] = !node[114] && !node[45];
    node[45] = !node[34] && !node[105];
    output[11][15] = node[45];
}
```

Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int ret;
    int parameter[8];
    int output[12][16];
    FILE *paramFile;
    FILE *outFile;

    paramFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (paramFile == NULL) {
        printf("I couldn't open the parameter file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    outFile = fopen(argv[2], "ab");
    if (outFile == NULL) {
        printf("Something went wrong with the output file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(1){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            ret=fscanf(paramFile, "%d", &parameter[i]);
            printf("parameter: %d\n", parameter[i]);
        }
        if(ret!=1){
            break;
        }
        for(j=0;j<12;j++){
            for(k=0;k<16;k++){
                output[j][k] = 2;
            }
        }
        evaluate(parameter,output);
        printf("Evaluation is done. \t %d\n",i);
        for(j=0;j<12;j++){ //SEG FAULT HERE
            for(k=0;k<16;k++){
                fprintf(outFile, "%d", output[j][k]);
            }
            fprintf(outFile,"\n");
        }
        fprintf(outFile,"\n\n\n");
    }
    printf("Closing files\n");  
    fclose(paramFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 116 nodes, 116+ outputs :D this is confusing.... I'd think about the naming (this doesn't fix the prob but would make this way easier to follow)

Comment: You should strongly consider using Valgrind to track buffer overflow problems.

Comment: is output[12][16] of int type in your code or did you just use int for simplicity in your question? If output is of pointer-to-something type then the issue would be that in evaluate(), node[] is allocated in the stack and doing output[i][j] = node[x] will assign pointers to stuff that goes out of scope.

Comment: Also, the "error checking" in the `fscanf()` loop is very strange, it only checks `ret` *after*  the entire loop has finished, thus only getting the last attempt's status. I/O is brittle, you should check every `fscanf()` call and abort if it fails.

Comment: Actually, this code does a Boolean evaluation, the elements in parameter are actually bits. It seemed best to just use int, but their values will only ever be 0 or 1.
The output is the same.

Comment: As for the 'error checking', it's not really meant to be error checking, it's just to correctly read in a file I'm generating myself. Possibly in a later stage this needs to be more robust, but for now, it not necessary to be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if there is at least two argument. This can provoque a segmentation fault too.

```
if (argc < 3)
    return -1;
```

Then, in evaluate, as they are fixe array you should pass in parameter

```
void evaluate(int parameter[8], int output[12][16]) {
    ...
}
```

You can also do this

```
void evaluate(int *parameter, int **output) {
    ...
}
```

I think the segfault can be avoid using one on this two declaration.

Comment: If i change the evaluate function as you suggest, I get this error:
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘evaluate’ from incompatible pointer type

I looked into two dimensional arrays, and most of the literature seems to suggest the way I did it originally.

Comment: for the two prototypes you have this error?
Well, I already have this kind of weird segfault.
Just try to put evaluate's directly in the main to see if you still have the segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, the int **output description is not compiling, so I can't check it, I get the following error when trying to compile it:`warning: passing argument 2 of ‘evaluate’ from incompatible pointer type`.
If I put the body of evaluate in the main then it runs without any segmentation faults.

Comment: Yeah, the fact it was segfaulting on the for mean that there was a problem with the memory. It's all about the argument passing, you can three things : first you can use malloc to allocate memory instead of define it with [12][16] and then use the **output. Second, you can let the body of evaluate in the main if you have no contraints about coding style. And third try with this kind of prototype
`void evaluate(int *parameter, int *output[16])`